# Paypal REST API - Credit-Card verification without charging

Tags: c#, rest, paypal, credit-card

I am using the Paypal Rest API in my C# .Net Framework 4.5.1 to verify credit-card payments.

I want to be able to verify the credit card of a customer while registering them to my website. What I am currently doing is, I charge the customer $0.01 and refund it back right away in order to verify the credit-card.

I don`t think this is practically the right way to verfiy the credit card. So, is it possible to verify credit-cards directly (without charging anything) using the Paypal Rest API ?

Answer (score 0):

Paypal has a sandbox mode where you can create fake users and do fake transactions

More info : https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/lifecycle/ug_sandbox/

Comment: Do you think I can verify real credit-cards in the sandbox mode ? In other words, if I create users with non existing credit-card accounts would I be able to find out that the credit-card info is wrong ?